# Слайдер с центральным елементом

Tags: javascript, css, slider, carousel

Зравствуйте!

Есть ли подобное готовое решения для слайдера с центральным слайдом по средине.

[image: Пример]

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это не сайт поиска тем

Comment: Советую замазать курсивный текст на изображении, чтобы не сочли за галимую рекламу.

Comment: http://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/pNjXWy

Answer (score 2):

[Адаптивный слайдер Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) с большим функционалом. Ваш вариант - Center Mode